# How to fetch website data using Ajax method

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the store location in this url

https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=Pennsylvani&distance=100

I currently use this method

```
def getAllStoreLocation():

session = requests.Session()
url = "https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=Pennsylvani&distance=100"

try:
    stateStoreSoup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    stateTagId = find_tag(stateStoreSoup)
    stateScript = stateStoreSoup.find("script", {"id":stateTagId})
    stateData = json.loads(stateScript.get_text(strip=True))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

tagId function

```
def find_tag(soup):
    script = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/json', 'id':re.compile(r'^((?!tb-djs).)*$')})
return script['id']
```

This works but gives too much unwanted data. I want to use the method in this answer

[how to fetch data from javascript loaded site using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139532/how-to-fetch-data-from-javascript-loaded-site-using-beautifulsoup)

to fetch the list of all the stores data

How can I fetch the store location data using the Ajax method in the answer. Please I'm only familiar with beautifulsoup and not Ajax so I will really appreciate a good explanation of the
code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(r"address\":({.*?})", r.text)]
    for item in match:
        item = eval(item)
        print("City: {:<30}, Address: {}".format(
            item['city'], item['address']))


main("https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=Pennsylvani&distance=100")
```

Output:

```
City: Montoursville                 , Address: 1015 N Loyalsock Ave
City: Mill Hall                     , Address: 167 Hogan Blvd
City: Lewisburg                     , Address: 120 Ajk Blvd
City: Selinsgrove                   , Address: 980 N Susquehanna Trl
City: Bloomsburg                    , Address: 100 Lunger Dr
City: Mansfield                     , Address: 1169 S Main St
City: State College                 , Address: 373 Benner Pike
City: State College                 , Address: 1665 N Atherton St
City: Coal Township                 , Address: 9300 State Route 61
City: Lewistown                     , Address: 10180 Us Highway 522 S
City: Elizabethville                , Address: 200 Kocher Ln
City: Saint Clair                   , Address: 500 Terry Rich Blvd
City: Sayre                         , Address: 1887 Elmira St
City: Hazle Township                , Address: 761 Airport Rd
City: Clearfield                    , Address: 100 Supercenter Dr
City: Painted Post                  , Address: 3217 Silverback Ln
City: Huntingdon                    , Address: 6716 Towne Center Blvd
City: Mechanicsburg                 , Address: 6520 Carlisle Pike Ste 550
City: Tamaqua                       , Address: 35 Plaza Dr
City: Horseheads                    , Address: 1400 County Rd 64
City: Tunkhannock                   , Address: 808 Hunter Hwy
City: Harrisburg                    , Address: 6535 Grayson Rd
City: Camp Hill                     , Address: 3400 Hartzdale Drive
City: Palmyra                       , Address: 100 No Londonderry Square
City: Wilkes Barre                  , Address: 2150 Wilkes Barre Twnsp Mktpl
City: Carlisle                      , Address: 60 Noble Blvd
City: Saint Marys                   , Address: 1102 Million Dollar Hwy
City: Lebanon                       , Address: 1355 E Lehman St
City: Pittston                      , Address: 390 Route 315 Hwy
City: Etters                        , Address: 50 Newberry Pkwy
City: Hamburg                       , Address: 1800 Tilden Ridge
City: Taylor                        , Address: 1325 Main
City: Du Bois                       , Address: 20 Industrial Dr
City: Shippensburg                  , Address: 100 S Conestoga Dr
City: Lehighton                     , Address: 1731 Blakeslee Boulevard Dr E
City: Altoona                       , Address: 2600 Plank Road Commons
City: Dickson City                  , Address: 900 Commerce Blvd
City: Hornell                       , Address: 1000 State Route 36
City: Watkins Glen                  , Address: 515 E 4th St
City: Temple                        , Address: 5370 Allentown Pike
City: Duncansville                  , Address: 200 Commerce Dr
City: Vestal                        , Address: 2405 Vestal Pkwy E
City: Wyomissing                    , Address: 1135 Berkshire Blvd
City: York                          , Address: 1000 Town Center Drive
City: York                          , Address: 2801 E Market St Bldg B
City: Olean                         , Address: 1869 Plaza Dr
City: Ephrata                       , Address: 890 E Main St
City: Johnson City                  , Address: 2 Gannett Dr
City: Lancaster                     , Address: 2030 Fruitville Pike
City: Bradford                      , Address: 50 Foster Brook Blvd
```

Updated Code:

```
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = [x.group(1, 2) for x in re.finditer(
        r',"id":(.*?),.*?address\":({.*?})', r.text)]
    for a, b in match:
        item = eval(b)
        idf = a
        print("ID: {}, City: {:<30}, Address: {}".format(idf,
                                                         item['city'], item['address']))


main("https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=Pennsylvani&distance=100")
```

Output:

```
ID: 1887, City: Montoursville                 , Address: 1015 N Loyalsock Ave
ID: 2528, City: Mill Hall                     , Address: 167 Hogan Blvd
ID: 1644, City: Lewisburg                     , Address: 120 Ajk Blvd
ID: 2185, City: Selinsgrove                   , Address: 980 N Susquehanna Trl
ID: 1794, City: Bloomsburg                    , Address: 100 Lunger Dr
ID: 1945, City: Mansfield                     , Address: 1169 S Main St
ID: 2230, City: State College                 , Address: 373 Benner Pike
ID: 1640, City: State College                 , Address: 1665 N Atherton St
ID: 2481, City: Coal Township                 , Address: 9300 State Route 61
ID: 1607, City: Lewistown                     , Address: 10180 Us Highway 522 S
ID: 3412, City: Elizabethville                , Address: 200 Kocher Ln
ID: 2535, City: Saint Clair                   , Address: 500 Terry Rich Blvd
ID: 2208, City: Sayre                         , Address: 1887 Elmira St
ID: 2255, City: Hazle Township                , Address: 761 Airport Rd
ID: 2129, City: Clearfield                    , Address: 100 Supercenter Dr
ID: 2992, City: Painted Post                  , Address: 3217 Silverback Ln
ID: 5470, City: Huntingdon                    , Address: 6716 Towne Center Blvd
ID: 1886, City: Mechanicsburg                 , Address: 6520 Carlisle Pike Ste 550
ID: 3634, City: Tamaqua                       , Address: 35 Plaza Dr
ID: 1976, City: Horseheads                    , Address: 1400 County Rd 64
ID: 2024, City: Tunkhannock                   , Address: 808 Hunter Hwy
ID: 1591, City: Harrisburg                    , Address: 6535 Grayson Rd
ID: 5888, City: Camp Hill                     , Address: 3400 Hartzdale Drive
ID: 2888, City: Palmyra                       , Address: 100 No Londonderry Square       
ID: 1623, City: Wilkes Barre                  , Address: 2150 Wilkes Barre Twnsp Mktpl   
ID: 2574, City: Carlisle                      , Address: 60 Noble Blvd
ID: 1792, City: Saint Marys                   , Address: 1102 Million Dollar Hwy
ID: 2023, City: Lebanon                       , Address: 1355 E Lehman St
ID: 2543, City: Pittston                      , Address: 390 Route 315 Hwy
ID: 4404, City: Etters                        , Address: 50 Newberry Pkwy
ID: 4612, City: Hamburg                       , Address: 1800 Tilden Ridge
ID: 4276, City: Taylor                        , Address: 1325 Main
ID: 1769, City: Du Bois                       , Address: 20 Industrial Dr
ID: 5358, City: Shippensburg                  , Address: 100 S Conestoga Dr
ID: 2169, City: Lehighton                     , Address: 1731 Blakeslee Boulevard Dr E   
ID: 2049, City: Altoona                       , Address: 2600 Plank Road Commons
ID: 1884, City: Dickson City                  , Address: 900 Commerce Blvd
ID: 2326, City: Hornell                       , Address: 1000 State Route 36
ID: 3221, City: Watkins Glen                  , Address: 515 E 4th St
ID: 2614, City: Temple                        , Address: 5370 Allentown Pike
ID: 4348, City: Duncansville                  , Address: 200 Commerce Dr
ID: 1835, City: Vestal                        , Address: 2405 Vestal Pkwy E
ID: 1670, City: Wyomissing                    , Address: 1135 Berkshire Blvd
ID: 2205, City: York                          , Address: 1000 Town Center Drive
ID: 1529, City: York                          , Address: 2801 E Market St Bldg B
ID: 2159, City: Olean                         , Address: 1869 Plaza Dr
ID: 2340, City: Ephrata                       , Address: 890 E Main St
ID: 5732, City: Johnson City                  , Address: 2 Gannett Dr
ID: 5200, City: Lancaster                     , Address: 2030 Fruitville Pike
ID: 3514, City: Bradford                      , Address: 50 Foster Brook Blvd
```

Comment: please do you mind explaining what is going on in match

Comment: @learner101 I've used `re` which is `Regex` where i matched `address` pattern within page source.

Comment: ok thank you, how could each store id be included in the fetch

Comment: each of the store has storeid that begins with # and is stored in class="result-element-store-number"

Comment: @learner101 next time you've to include such details within your question itself where you can [edit] it. anyway I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have noted the answer you pass out using anohter python lib requests.

if you have not install the lib,please try `pip install requests`.

and try to use this urls like this to fetch data

https://www.walmart.com/store/finder/electrode/api/stores?singleLineAddr=Pennsylvani&distance=25

Comment: how were you able to find the url

Comment: you need try analysis the network request by some tools.  In Chorme you can press f12 ,you will see the develop tools and find network tab, try to change in param in page ,you will find the page made some ajax request,when you change params